# Ubuntu 12.04 won't boot, only shows a blinking white line

Tags: boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

I am trying to turn on my computer (Dell Mini 910 netbook) and after the BIOS setup screen it just shows a blinking white line. Please help!

Comment: A line or only a cursor?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Please add extra detail about your issue. Can you give spec details?

Comment: Have you checked this question? -> [My computer boots to a black screen. What options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

I had 12.04.1 and for some reason it would not boot anymore.  So I had to reinstall a windows operating system on the computer and then try again.Sometime Ubuntu can be funny.